# Convert Json to Array in Swift 5

Tags: swift

All the examples I find are using dictionary types, for example: `user: x, book: y`

but how can I convert this type of Json which doesn't contain a key?

```
["1","137","56","56"]
```

This is of type `String?`

I tried:

```
struct Candidate: Decodable {
    var S: String?
}

let chainsAllowed = ["1","137","56","56"]

let jsonObjectData = chainsAllowed.data(using: .utf8)!
let candidate = try? JSONDecoder().decode(
    Candidate.self,
    from: jsonObjectData
)
```

but I get nil. How can I convert it into an array?

Thanks

Comment: '["1","137","56","56"]' is not even in the JSON format, duh...

Comment: JSON format be like ["userA": "1", "userB": "137", "userC": "56", "userD": "56"], bro

Comment: `try?` is literally saying "If there are any errors, please disregard them and just give me `nil`". If you caught the error instead and took a look at it, you would have gotten a useful error message.

Comment: For anyone saying it's not even JSON, it actually **is** valid JSON. A JSON text can be any of `false / null / true / object / array / number / string`. See https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8259#section-2

Comment: @ElTomato lol it is. It's actually downloaded from AWS DyanamoDB with type: `AWSJSON`

Comment: Umm...  I'm sorry.  You are right.

Comment: Nitpicking: It's only JSON if this "string representation" is Unicode  ;)
JSON is actually a binary format, which just happens to be Unicode - and is thus human readable (which was a genius idea, by the way). ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do this:

```swift
import Foundation

let chainsAllowed = #"["1","137","56","56"]"#

let jsonObjectData = chainsAllowed.data(using: .utf8)
let candidate = try? JSONDecoder().decode(
    [String].self,
    from: jsonObjectData!
)

print(candidate!)
```

Output:

```
["1", "137", "56", "56"]
```

> For your information: An array **is actually perfectly valid JSON**. In fact, a JSON text can be any of `false / null / true / object / array / number / string`. See https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8259#section-2